# How to make renderer transparent in three js Trackball control (r87)?

Tags: three.js

I have two renderer in one canvas as, I want that renderer to be transparent I applied this below code. but it didn't work out. could anybody help me out?

`var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { alpha: true } );`
`renderer.setClearColor( 0x000000, 0 );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>Don't use `setClearColor` if you want a transparent background. It overrides `alpha`, which is what makes the background transparent.</s> **EDIT: Using `setClearColor` with the `WebGLRenderer.alpha` property is fine. Just remember to include an alpha parameter if you want the background to be transparent: `renderer.setClearColor( hexColor, alphaValue );`**

I don't understand what you mean by "two renderer in one canvas" though. That sounds dangerous, at best. If you're trying to draw two things to the same canvas, consider combining them into one scene, or render two scenes using the same renderer.

(This also has nothing to do with `TrackballControl`.)

Comment: That totally makes sense. Thank you so much for your suggestion to use one renderer. It worked out :)

Comment: Why do you say "Don't use setClearColor...it overrides alpha"? `setClearColor( 0x000000, 0 );`

Comment: At the time, I missed the second parameter in Mhd's function call. Calling `setClearColor( 0x000000 );` would result in a black background because the `alpha` parameter defaults to `1`. My bad for missing that. Mhd's code likely worked as-is for the transparency, and it was the two renderers which were causing the problems.